# Reconnect to a running process

Tags: linux, mysql, process

I was trying to import an SQL file to a MySQL replication server using `mysql -u -p -h ... < my_dump.sql` using a PuTTY client from my laptop. Unfortunately, my network cable got chewed by my cat, so i lost connection with the server for a few seconds - just enough to terminate my session. I've reconnected to the server, used `ps aux |grep mysql` and saw that the process was still running. Is there any possible way to reattach that process to the current tty?

I know I could have used `screen`, or `nohup` but this was supposed to be a short import.

Comment: should be possible, but I can not remember exactly how. If you look in `/proc/«pid»/fd` you will find files for stdin = `0`, stdout = `1`, stderr = `2`. This may be a way to allow reconnection. I have in the past recovered a video that I was watching, but deleted (`rm`), by copying a higher numbered file.

Comment: I think you can use gdb. Give it a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1543/66388) and the linked Q&A. BTW, next time you can try to run it with `nohup` (so at least it will finish however) or use `screen` or, even better, something like no-machine. Good Luck.

Comment: @richard this did the trick. I was able to check whether the import went ok. However i couldn't connect to the TTY. Thanks!